# How to resolve exception in thread “main” javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: not bound?

Tags: java, jboss5.x, jms-topic

I'm trying to create a jms publisher/subscriber chat application in eclipse.

```
import java.util.Properties;
    import javax.jms.JMSException;
    import javax.jms.Message;
    import javax.jms.MessageListener;
    import javax.jms.TextMessage;
    import javax.jms.Topic;
    import javax.jms.TopicConnection;
    import javax.jms.TopicConnectionFactory;
    import javax.jms.TopicSession;
    import javax.naming.Context;
    import javax.naming.InitialContext;
    import javax.naming.NamingException;
    public class TopicConsumer implements MessageListener {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException, NamingException {
            System.out.println(".....Entering JMS example TopicConsumer....");  
            Context context = TopicConsumer.getInitialContext();
            TopicConnectionFactory topicConnectionFactory = (TopicConnectionFactory) context.lookup("ConnectionFactory");
            Topic topic = (Topic) context.lookup("topic/zaneacademy_jms_tutorial_01");
            TopicConnection topicConnection = topicConnectionFactory.createTopicConnection();
            TopicSession topicSession = topicConnection.createTopicSession(false, TopicSession.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            topicSession.createSubscriber(topic).setMessageListener(new TopicConsumer());
            topicConnection.start();
            System.out.println("......Exiting JMS Example TopicConsumer.....");
            }
            public void onMessage(Message message) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Incoming Messages: " + ((TextMessage)message).getText());
                } catch (JMSException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            public static Context getInitialContext() throws JMSException, NamingException {
                Properties props = new Properties();
                props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial", "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
                props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "org.jboss.naming");
                props.setProperty("java.naming.provider.url", "localhost:1099");
                Context context = new InitialContext(props);
                return context;
            }
        }
```

trying to run the program I'm getting the following errors in console

```
.....Entering JMS example TopicConsumer....
Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: zaneacademy_jms_tutorial_01 not bound
    at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getBinding(NamingServer.java:564)
    at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getBinding(NamingServer.java:572)
    at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getObject(NamingServer.java:578)
    at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.lookup(NamingServer.java:317)
    at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.lookup(NamingServer.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:669)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:629)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at TopicConsumer.main(TopicConsumer.java:19)
```

Answer (score 0):

As it says in the exception the name `zaneacademy_jms_tutorial_01` is not bound.
You need to configure it and assign it to the `topic/zaneacademy_jms_tutorial_01`.

I would say that the problem is your `getInitialContext()` which you configure manaully, instead of returning the probably already configured context by `new InitialContext();`